# Can't remove canonical link in WordPress with Yoast SEO Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook, yoast

So I'm trying to remove the canonical link in the header of WordPress for paginated pages but all the suggestions I tried aren't working.

Here is my code which is in my functions.php file:

```
function my_add_noindex_tags(){
    $paged = intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

    if(is_search() || is_404() ) :
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">';
    endif;

    if ($paged >= 2) :
        add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false', 10, 1 );

        remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');

        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">';
    endif;
}
add_action('wp_head','my_add_noindex_tags', 4 );
```

I know the code inside `if ($paged >= 2) :` runs because this tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">` is in the head section.

Anyone know where I might be going wrong.

The issue here is the canonical link added by [Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/) aren't properly removed as expected.

Cheers

Comment: You must find out what is responsible for inserting the code and act accordingly. Where did you find out that the `wpseo_canonical` filter is a filter you can use?

Comment: Hi @josephting I'm using the yoast seo plugin, so according to their [API](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/) I use `add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' );` to remove the canonical. But it's not working

Comment: Perhaps something else is printing it instead. Without knowing what plugins and/or themes you're using, it's not possible to pinpoint the cause. Since you've already applied the appropriate filter to remove canonical link inserted by yoast and also the native `rel_canonical` action, there might be something else that is inserting the canonical link. And since `rel_canonical` is added to `embed_head` action as well, it probably won't work but try adding `remove_action('embed_head', 'rel_canonical')` as well.

Comment: @josephting using `remove_action('embed_head', 'rel_canonical')` completely broke the site. Won't even load up now. Lucky I'm developing on localhost

Comment: It shouldn't break the site unless you forgot the colon (`;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the [Yoast SEO codes](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/), it seems like the canonical action is added to `wpseo_head` action.

You either have to use priority 1 when adding your function to run in `wp_head` to get this to execute properly, or do it with the appropriate method below ie. using `wpseo_head` action.

```
function remove_canonical() {
    $paged = intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

    if ($paged >= 2) {
        add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'wpseo_head', 'remove_canonical', 4);
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks m8

Answer (score 0):

For me only adding this to init action worked

```
add_action('init', function() {

   add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false', 10 );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

All these answers didn't help me and i couldn't find the right answer for my scenario:

I had to set priority to higher than 10 because apparently Yoast changes the url at priority 10 so if you want to change their url you have to set a higher priority:

Change the canonical url with a custom function:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'change_canonical', 20 );
```

Delete the canonical url:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false', 20 );
```

Be aware that if you do not set a priority it will use priority 10 as the default and it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but for the right implementation, you need to run 'wpseo_canonical' filter directly:

```
function remove_canonical_pagination() {
    $paged = intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

    if ($paged >= 2) {
        return false;
    }
}
add_action( 'wpseo_canonical', 'remove_canonical_pagination', 4);
```